# Mongoose findOne scope doubts

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to this javascript thing and have i have some doubts about mongoose 'find' scope's.

I wrote the code below to try to understand the problem.

The code below searches into a Shopping collection and then search for the Stores assigned to this Shopping.

storeMap is a hashmap of storeId => storeObject, but when the Store.findOne scope end, storeMap seems to rollback to an empty array...

```
 var storeMap = {};
 Shopping.findOne({ name: shoppingName }, function(err, shopping){
                    shopping.stores.forEach(function(storeId) {
                            Store.findOne({_id: storeId}, function(err, store) {
                                    if(err) console.log(err);
                                    console.log(store); //prints out store data
                                    storeMap[storeId] = store;
                                    console.log(storeMap); //prints out store data
                            });
                            console.log(storeMap); //prints out an empty array
                    });
            });
```

So, why my storeMap array is printing an empty array instead of a store array?

Answer (score 1):

`Store.findOne`, like many things in node.js, is asynchronous and takes a [callback](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks).  Your callback is where `storeMap` gets set:

```
function(err, store) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(store); //prints out store data
    storeMap[storeId] = store;
    console.log(storeMap); //prints out store data
}
```

And this only runs once `Store.findOne` finishes its work, which could take a long time.

The following line, `console.log(storeMap);` executes immediately, however--before the callback runs.  Thus, storeMap is still empty.

I recommend looking at a few examples/explanations of the callback pattern in node.js, it's fundamental to understand.